# Qt push button connect error, Visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am trying to make a simple button-text box application in QT. I added the button and I have 4 errors when I try to connect it.

```
#include "poatelovim.h"
#include "qmessagebox.h"
poatelovim::poatelovim(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(pushButtonClicked()));
    //ui->pushButton->setText("Hello");
}

//void MyClass::pushButtonClicked() // defined in .h under public/private slots:
//{
    //QMessageBox::information(this, "Information", "Just clicked Ui PushButton"); // #include <QtGui/QMessageBox>
//}
```

[image: The Errors]

Comment: Try this way : `connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::pushButtonClicked);`

Comment: `ui` isn't a pointer here, so use `.` rather `->` for accessing it's member element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for connect signal click to your slot:

```
connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWindow::pushButtonClicked);
```

Or your way like this:

```
connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(pushButtonClicked(bool)));

void MyClass::pushButtonClicked(bool clicked) // defined in .h under public/private slots:
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Information", "Just clicked Ui PushButton"); // #include <QtGui/QMessageBox>
}
```

[QPushButton signal clicked](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) : This signal is emitted when the button is activated, **If the button is checkable, checked is true if the button is checked, or false if the button is unchecked.**